# How to fix "nsurlconnection finished with error - code 1100 " error for UIWebView in IOS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode10, ios12

I am working on an existing project where `UIWebview` is used to load html string to load js files for loading contents downloaded from our server.Currently `UIWebview` is not able to load the contents in IOS which is perfectly loading in Android.

I have tried to switch to WKWebView but still no luck.

```
self.webContentView.delegate = self;
NSString* html = [player getHTMLString];
NSString* baseURL = [player getBaseURLPath];
[self.pageLoadingActivity startAnimating];
[self.webContentView loadHTMLString:html baseURL: [NSURL URLWithString: baseURL]];
```

EDIT------

After debugging sometime I found I was getting two 1100 error.
It seemed like two file were missing or app was not able to read them.
Now whenever I am hitting shouldStartLoadWithRequest with 
request
 URL:

> file:///Users/ealpha4tech/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2CA71983-9996-44D6-944F-34E3EAFAE96D/data/Containers/Data/Application/6A19ABBA-CB68-4EE4-AC02-6AD3CB8A5A68/Documents/icplayer/icplayer/D2D6AFFF93CB2CFCB1640484F5429D89.cache.html

I am getting 1100 error.(the above file is present though)

Comment: Now that you know the files are missing, you need to find out why they are not there.

Answer (score 0):

So as a guess, I would say `[player getHTMLString]` is the problem.

> [NSURLErrorFileDoesNotExist](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrorfiledoesnotexist?language=objc): The specified file doesn’t exist.

This is a local file error.

I'm guessing that `-getHTMLString` is trying to load a file out of the app, but that file is not being included in the app.

I could help more if you provide 2 things.

1. Provide the source for `-getHTMLString`
2. Use `NSLog()` to print value of `[player getBaseURLPath]`.

---

**UPDATE**

In looking at your output, I noticed `…ments/icplayer/icplayer/D2D6A…`. I think the proper path should only have one `icplayer` not two. Look to see if it's getting repeated somehow.

Comment: Hi @Jeffery 
Thank you for your response. 
Below is the code

- (NSString *)getHTMLString
{
    return [self.template renderObject:self error:NULL];
}

- (NSString *)getBaseURLPath
{
    return [@"file://" stringByAppendingString:[self.lessonMainXmlPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
}

html string is getting build from a template.

Comment: @RR_Pradhan please update your question with the new information.

Comment: The directory is correct.There are two icplayer folder. I tried to load the file from app resources and now I am not getting 1100 error but UIWebView is showing blank page.It is even going to webViewDidFinishLoad method